# C++ - How do placeholders work (particularly in boost::type_erasure)?

Tags: c++, boost

I’m trying to gain an understanding of type erasure techniques, as discussed [here](https://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2013/11/18/type-erasure-part-i/) and implemented in adobe::poly and Boost::TypeErasure.  Unfortunately, I seem to be missing a fundamental understanding of placeholders; I’m currently struggling to understand the following code from the boost documentation ([here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/boost_typeerasure/concept.html)):

```
std::vector<int> vec;
any<has_push_back<_self, int>, _self&> c(vec);
```

My questions are as follows:

1)  I believe I've seen several examples of placeholders – in lambdas, Boost MPL, etc.  There seems to be a convention to specify these with a leading underscore.  My understanding is that, per the standard, identifiers with leading underscores are reserved, at least at file/global scope.  If this is correct, that would suggest that the placeholder is defined somewhere.  So where and how is the “_self” placeholder defined?  (I see a declaration in the library, but that's all - there's no implementation.  Is that all that's needed?)

2)  Presumably, each library defines their placeholders – but they’re often identically named (for example, “_1”, “_2”, …).  So when using multiple libraries together in a translation unit, a developer generally would need to explicitly qualify the usage to avoid ambiguity/collision?  Or does ADL somehow mitigate this?  Is it best practice to explicitly qualify the placeholders, or is this eschewed to avoid excessive “syntactical noise”?

3)  In the code above, it seems that “_self” is replaced with std::vector during the instantiation of “any”.  Is this somehow implicitly deduced from this variable declaration/initialization statement?  (Perhaps via a ctor template???)  If not, how does this work?

4)  Are these placeholders always type specifiers for template arguments?  Is this the canonical usage that is common across metaprogramming/lambda source libraries?

Thanks in advance for your thoughts on this!

Comment: The standards reserves names that have two underscores (`__`) or start with one underscore and one upper case (`_A`). `se__lf` and `_Self` are reserved, but `_self` is not reserved.

Comment: Namespaces... namespaces

Comment: One question per question!

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, placeholders are simply unique types that can be "switched upon" in template metaprogramming.

Usually, when there are multiple placeholders of the same "kind" they are related like e.g.:

```
template <int N>
struct my_placeholder_t {
    enum { value = N };
};

typedef my_placeholder_t<0> _0;
typedef my_placeholder_t<1> _1;
typedef my_placeholder_t<2> _2;
...
```

This relation merely makes it easier to write code for generically, but doesn't matter to the enduser:

```
typedef /*implementation-defined*/ _0;
typedef /*implementation-defined*/ _1;
typedef /*implementation-defined*/ _2;
...
```

---

The implementation will use the placeholders at a later stage. The placeholders are usually encoded in a type:

```
auto et = foo(_2, _1);
```

would result in an object of e.g. `template_expr<something, ..., my_placeholder_t<2>, my_placeholder_t<1>>` (see [Expression templates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expression_templates)).

At a later stage these types would then be "interpreted", e.g. when you do:

do_action(et, make_tuple("ignored!", "something", 42));

The implementation of `do_action` could interpret the placeholders to get their corresponding elements from that tuple, e.g. This is what the `bind` library functions (std::bind, boost::bind, boost::lambda::bind, boost::phoenix::bind, boost::mpl::bind...) all tend to do.

---

In Boost TypeErasure the placeholder `_self` is mainly used to specify qualification of `this` arguments in member function *concept* specifications.